# Using multiple IF and OR statements with calculations

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate unit price based on quantity.

I have nested IF functions to check the quantity and multiply that by the correct unit price.

#### Unit Price Table

| QTY >= | QTY <= | Unit $ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 4 |
| 5.01 | 11 | 3.2 |
| 11.01 | 15.5 | 2.8 |
| 15.51 | 20.5 | 2.7 |
| 20.51 | ~ | 2.3 |

My formula only works up until the third IF function and I can't figure out why:

```
=IF(AV2<=5,AV2*4,
   IF(OR(AV2>=5.01,AV2<=11),AV2*3.2,
     IF(OR(AV2>=11.01,AV2<=15.5),AV2*2.8,
       IF(OR(AV2>=15.51,AV2<=20.5),AV2*2.7,
          IF(AV2>=20.51,AV2*2.3)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `AND` instead of `OR`

```
=IF(AV2<=5                   ,AV2*4,
 IF(AND(AV2>=5.01, AV2<=11)  ,AV2*3.2,
 IF(AND(AV2>=11.01,AV2<=15.5),AV2*2.8,
 IF(AND(AV2>=15.51,AV2<=20.5),AV2*2.7,
 IF(AV2>=20.51               ,AV2*2.3,)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> **My preferred formula**
>  `=AV2 * MIN(FILTER(B2:B6, A2:A6<=AV2))`

## Two Approaches

1. **Reverse Order**
   A more efficient approach that is based on your current IF function formula. Included a version for  (a) the IFS function, and another with (b) multiple IF functions.
2. **Lookup Table**
   My recommended approach. Simpler more reusable formula, and easier price management. Included a version with (a) INDEX/MATCH for sorted lookup data, and another with (b) FILTER/MIN for both sorted and unsorted lookup data.

## 1. Reverse Order Approach

The order of conditions in [your formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123617) (and [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123618/)) imposes the need of an upper limit in each condition.  Simply reversing the order addresses this need using the preceding condition and eliminates a lot of unnecessary code.  The first condition has no upper limit by design so it doesn't matter that no other condition precedes it.

There is unnecessary duplication in the **value_if_true** arguments.  They all calculate the product of price and quantity.  Each price is of course unique, but the quantity `AV2` is a common factor.  Calculating the product separately reduces the code and makes the formula easier to follow and maintain.

#### 1a.   IFS Function

```
=AV2*IFS(AV2>20.5, 2.3,
         AV2>15.5, 2.7,
         AV2>11, 2.8,
         AV2> 5, 3.2,
         1, 4)

# Note: Condition=1 is equivalent to TRUE
```

Uses IFS instead of multiple IF functions.  The formula is shorter and easier to maintain.

### 1b.   Multiple IF Functions

```
=AV2*IF(AV2>20.5, 2.3,
   IF(AV2>15.5, 2.7,
     IF(AV2>11, 2.8,
       IF(AV2>5, 3.2,
         4))))
```

Works just as well as a single IFS function but is a longer formula that may be more difficult to maintain.

## Lookup Table Approach

This centralizes and separates the quantity and price data from the actual formula.

It is easier to review, add, remove, and modify pricing data, the actual formula is simplified, and there is less need to edit it simply to make pricing changes.

Also opens the possibility of centralizing the pricing combinations for different products and even sharing a common formula for all products.

#### Sample Lookup Data

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **QTY >=** | **Unit Price** |
| **2** | 0 | 4 |
| **3** | 5.01 | 3.2 |
| **4** | 11.01 | 2.8 |
| **5** | 15.51 | 2.7 |
| **6** | 20.51 | 2.3 |

#### 2a.   INDEX and MATCH

```
=AV2*INDEX(B2:B6,
   MATCH(AV2, A2:A6))
```

Use **only** if the table is sorted by Quantity in ascending order or that sort is included in the formula.

#### 2b.   FILTER and MIN

```
=AV2*MIN(FILTER(
    B2:B6, A2:A6<=AV2))
```

Will work regardless of the sort order.  FILTER eliminates prices that aren't valid due to insufficient quantity, then MIN returns the lowest one from any remaining.